# Create a user comment field linked to read-only Oracle database

Tags: excel, oracle, vba

We have an application to track work orders (hundreds of thousands) built on an Oracle database. Data entry is cumbersome and report features non-existent. IT is inflexible. We do not get support from that end. Accordingly, users have created Excel "tools" to run queries and make sense of data using ADO or ODBC connections.

What we also need is a way to record comments on specific work order (WO) records and have those comments travel with those records somehow. There are multiple users using their own spreadsheets, all querying the same database.

I'm envisioning a junction-table approach, perhaps using Access, where some VBA could take a users comment from the row in the worksheet, capture the WO number, user id, date, and comment text and store it in an Access table. Those fields could then be retrieved by some more code. This would allow any user to see all comments by any other user related to a specific WO.

I'd greatly appreciate feedback ... on the practicality, preferable constructive, but brutally honest is ok too.

Much thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Sounds like IT has a management/capacity issue.  If this is Business critical (ROI on this is justified among all the other projects IT is doing) and IT built the applications and can change them...  This type of issue should go up the management chain.  Developing outside the system is asking for headache's down the road. IMO (IT developer/Manager for 20+ years)

Comment: I agree.  Years ago I came across software that could take the file of a report that had been printed  on a dot matrix printer and allow the user to extract data from the report and summerise the data and reformat the presentation. APPAULING!  IT'S AN ENOUMOUS BODGE AND SHOULDN'T HAPPEN!   Your company needs to sort out it's processes rather than make them worse.

Comment: @HarveyFrench - Any chance that software was named after a butterfly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monarch_(software)

Comment: 'Cor version 12.1 sounds excellent.  perhaps Kevin's company should consider it instead of using excel.

Comment: Thanks for the perspectives. They make good sense. The software is a work management suite called Portal J from Indus who I think have been absorbed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from this being a horrible mess you could:

1. use SQL Server instead of access - you can get a free copy that will probably cater for your needs.  Access will also work, but it is bodge.  SQL server is more professional!
2. I would avoid doing data entry in excel. You could build a front end (possibly in Access with SQL Server backend) that allows data entry.  You could add pretty simple code to all your workbooks, which will probably reference code that will be in an excel addin.  The addin has code to simply open an access database, open a form and find the WO that the user was viewing in excel.

2a. Or you could use an excel addin with a data entry form, to do data entry, but beware managing the locking, refreshing and update of displayed data.

3. Creating excel addins is easy, (re-)distributing them is easy, access (or whatever front end you use) is designed to do record management (ie lock and update or lock and cancel or just view) etc.... Plus you want to avoid addinghte same or similar code to all your workbooks.
4. Each users workbook would have very simple code.  Just to tell the addin what WO you want to operate on.
5. Do you have sharepoint?  If so Access 2013 can deliver forms as webpages - very easily, so you might not even have to manage a front end access file.

Happier now?

Comment: Thanks Harvey. And yes, a little.  Hadn't thought about Excel addins or the SharePoint angle. There might be something there. A couple of the IT guys that support SP are interested in actually promoting productivity improvements. Not ready to give up yet.

Comment: I recommend buying the wrox access 2013 book. It's all about access web apps on SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

For those that may stumble on this post, what we ended up doing was use VBA to store comments in a separate SQL database. Users double click the cell with the WO number to get an input form prompting for comments with options to add new, append or remove existing. Entries are passed to the SQL db and also to columns in the worksheet so users can see all the entries. Time stamp/Network ID provides when/who provided comment. Existing comments are fetched when users re-open file. Works great.